# I cant understand how (for example) deepMinds breakout bot learns while it plays

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, openai-gym

Im trying to solve the cartpole problem in openAIs gym. My approach is deep Q learning.

Im able to get a good score if I first generate a bunch of training data. Then train my network on this data. And after that I run my agent again, this time with 100% exploit.

The difference is that my model don't learn progressively. I must first generate training data, train and then it has learnt, so it looks something like:

`generate training data -> train -> play`.

What I want to do is:

`play -> train -> play better` etc..

Following this approach, using the exact same neural network and hyper parameters my agent is not improving.

My guess is that there is something very fundamental that I am missing. So what I am looking for is where my logic can be at fault.

My entire code if you want to try it out.

```
import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import random
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense

# Deep Q-learning Model
class Model:
    def __init__(self, environment):
        self.env = gym.make(environment)
        self.amount_obs, self.amount_actions = self.environment()

        # Amount of episodes and steps per episode
        self.episodes = 1000

        self.gamma = 0.95  # Discount future rate
        self.alpha = 0.001 # Learning rate

        # Epsilon = explore/exploite factor
        self.epsilon       = 1.0    # 100% explore initally
        self.epsilon_min   = 0.01
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.995

        self.batch_size = 50
        self.model      = self.create_net()

    def create_net(self):
        # Neural-net
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.amount_obs, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(self.amount_actions, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.alpha))
        return model

    def environment(self):
        observation_space = len(self.env.observation_space.sample())
        # Space.n gets number of actions
        action_space = self.env.action_space.n
        return observation_space, action_space

    def act(self, state, always_exploit=False):
        # Explore or exploite
        if random.random() <= self.epsilon and not always_exploit:
            # Random action (explore)
            return random.randrange(self.amount_actions)
        # Predict an action (exploite)
        possible_actions = self.model.predict(state)
        return np.argmax(possible_actions[0])

    def train(self, episode):
        for steps in episode:
            state, action, reward, next_state, done = steps

            if done:
                target = reward
            else:
                target = reward + self.gamma * \
                       np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0])

            target_state = self.model.predict(state)
            target_state[0][action] = target
            self.model.fit(state, target_state, epochs=2, verbose=0)

    def play(self):
        for i in range(self.episodes):

            state = self.env.reset()
            state = np.reshape(state, [1, self.amount_obs])
            episode = []
            episode_reward = 0
            done = False

            while not done:

                #self.env.render()

                # Decide action
                action = self.act(state)

                next_state, reward, done, _ = self.env.step(action)
                next_state = np.reshape(next_state,
                             [1, self.amount_obs])

                # save the previous state, action, reward, and done
                episode.append(
                        (state, action, reward, next_state, done))

                state = next_state

                episode_reward = episode_reward + reward

            print("Episode {} - totals {}".format(i, episode_reward))
            # Train the episode
            self.train(episode)

        # Decrease epsilon
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay

# initialize gym environment and the agent
model = Model('CartPole-v0')
#model = Model('MountainCar-v0')
#model = Model('Acrobot-v1')
model.play()
```

Comment: I train after each episode on randomly selected data from previous episodes